# What does the FAIL2BAN BadBots block ? Only Authentication related?

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04, fail2ban

I  am wondering if fail2ban is used only in order to block IP addresses that are from which there are authentication failures (SSH / HTTP auth. etc) or that it is also used for blocking Bots which crawl the content of web pages (normal webpage traffic) ??

I know there is a BadBots part in the jail.conf file, but is that only blocking bots that try to break through authentication ? Or can I block bots from visiting my web pages (and scraping) with this ??

Thanks,
Lex

Answer (score 0):

`fail2ban` parses logfiles for patterns. It's up to you how you define these.

Answer (score 0):

apache-badbots works on known useragent strings. See how the filter is written:

```
/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-badbots.conf
```

For authentication brute force atacks, see apache-auth nginx-http-auth or lighttpd-auth.